# After installing binary to another directory, error "No such file or directory"

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, snap, paths

After uninstalling a program with apt and reinstalling it in another location (ex. pypy with snap), running the program from command line reports `bash: /usr/bin/pypy: No such file or directory`, but `which pypy` correctly gives `/snap/bin/pypy`. How do I get the shell to recognize the new installation location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `hash -r`. See [What does hash -r command do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952137/what-does-hash-r-command-do)

Alternatively restart the shell with `exec bash`.