# edit chmod for youtube-dl

Tags: software-installation, permissions, youtube, chmod

I'm still learning my way around linux. I tried installing youtube-dl following these instructions https://itsfoss.com/download-youtube-linux/
When I got to `sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl` I got a message saying there was no file at that location, so I went looking for it and found it here `sudo chmod a+rx /usr/bin/youtube-dl`

Came to download audio and got "YouTube said: Unable to extract video data"

Bit more searching showed that to update on ubuntu I should purge and `sudo pip3 install youtube-dl` then i can update youtube-dl

now i'm getting a message saying "bash: /usr/bin/youtube-dl: No such file or directory
"

that's the address i used in the original chmod command so i think something is still looking there.
looked at removing the chmod change with this:

```
chmod: cannot access '/usr/bin/youtube-dl': No such file or directory
```

...tbh i dont know linux well enough to have any idea whats happening.

thanks

Comment: See [After installing binary to another directory, error "No such file or directory"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1215615/after-installing-binary-to-another-directory-error-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: the easiest way to download `youtube-dl` is from the ubuntu software center