# Why is my system only looking in /snap for binaries?

Tags: apt, snap

I tried to use snap to install node.  The package was stale.  So, I `snap remove`'d that, and I installed node via apt from the nodesource PPA.  Great:

```
$ node -v
v14.15.5
```

However, when I try to use `npm`, I get the following error:

```
$ npm
bash: /snap/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

This is weird to me, since `/usr/bin` is on my `$PATH` and:

```
$ ls /usr/bin/npm
/usr/bin/npm
```

What has snap done to my system's normal method of looking for binaries in `$PATH`?

Also, how do I fix this?

Comment: Does the behavior change after running `hash -d npm`?

Comment: @steeldriver yes.  So, had my terminal had already previously looked up the location of `npm`, and had stored in somewhere for quick lookup?

Comment: Yes - see fo example [What does hash -r command do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952137/what-does-hash-r-command-do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shell doesn't constantly search for binaries once it's found one-- to do so would be a waste of time in most cases. It caches the result. That bites hard if you end up removing a binary after it's already cached where it found it, though.

You can fix this by simply starting a new shell, or clearing the cache in an existing shell with `hash -r`.

Comment: "starting a new shell" — is that equivalent to "open a new terminal window"? So this looking for binaries / caching happens every time a new terminal window is opened?

Comment: Opening a new window does start a new shell, but that's not the only way to do it (e.g. you might use screen, or byobu, or SSH...).