# Can't run command installed with apt after removing the snap of that package

Tags: 20.04, snap, tree

I wanted to install the tree command to look at /var/www.
I can ls /var/www and the directories it contains.  Permissions on those directories are set to 755.

I ran

```
sudo snap install tree
```

thereafter running

```
tree /var/www
```

returns the message

```
/var/www [error opening dir]
```

I removed the tree snap with

```
sudo snap remove --purge tree
```

...and installed tree with

```
sudo apt install tree
```

Now when I try to use tree I get

```
-bash: /snap/bin/tree: No such file or directory
```

How to I banish the snap version of tree from my machine completely?

Comment: It's likely not in your "machine" - just in your shell's hash table. Try `hash -d tree` or `hash -r` to clear the whole table - see for example [Why is my system only looking in /snap for binaries?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317554/why-is-my-system-only-looking-in-snap-for-binaries)

Comment: That fixed the problem.  Thanks.  Looks like "snap remove" is somewhat incomplete.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my system only looking in /snap for binaries?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317554/why-is-my-system-only-looking-in-snap-for-binaries)

Answer (score 2):

[Steeldriver had the solution!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324317/cant-run-command-installed-with-apt-after-removing-the-snap-of-that-package/1324320#comment2257109_1324317)

> It's likely not in your "machine" - just in your shell's hash table. Try `hash -d tree` or `hash -r` to clear the whole table - see for example [Why is my system only looking in /snap for binaries?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317554/why-is-my-system-only-looking-in-snap-for-binaries)