# Cmake returning bash cmake-3.18.6-Linux-x86_64.sh --skip-license --prefix=/usr/local

Tags: bash, cmake

I have installed `cmake` to `/usr/local` but when I use it, receive this:

```
bash cmake-3.18.6-Linux-x86_64.sh --skip-license --prefix=/usr/local
```

I run `cmake --version`, but:

```
bash: /usr/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `hash -d cmake`. See related [Can't run command installed with apt after removing the snap of that package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324317/cant-run-command-installed-with-apt-after-removing-the-snap-of-that-package) and [Remove path to uninstalled codeblocks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654885/remove-path-to-uninstalled-codeblocks)

Comment: What was wrong with [deb-packaged version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/cmake)?